# How to Make The "Title Bar" Bigger

Tags: beamer, templates, presentations

This is hard to describe by words but the following code and the picture is worth more than a thousand words I can use to describe my question.

Thanks in advance

```
\documentclass[12pt, xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty  %no navigation pane
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}
%\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}{\makebox[-1em][r]{}}

\title[A Large Topic Name for the Presentation]{A Large Topic Name for the Presentation That Cannot Be Shortened}
\author[John Doe]{John Doe}
%\subtitle{}
%\setbeamercovered{transparent} 
%\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} 
%\log_2o
\institute[]{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{image-placeholder.jpg}}
\date[{\includegraphics[height=2mm]{image-placeholder.jpg}}]{Some Day in 2021} 
%\subject{} 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[noframenumbering, plain]
\titlepage
\end{frame}



\section{some section}
\subsection{some subsection}
\begin{frame}{\centerline{A Slide}}

\vspace{12em}

I need the middle section of the bottom line to be larger sacrificing equally from the "name" and the "frame number" stips. 
$$\downarrow $$

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: My Question]

Comment: I am aware that you use `CambridgeUS`, while the OP of the linked question uses the `Madrid` theme instead. However, both themes internally load `\useoutertheme{infolines}`, which makes the answer to the linked question also applicable to your code.

Comment: This actually did the trick, thanks. A follow up: How can I make the author name to "flushleft" not "center". I think that will look much better.

Comment: Actually, let me alter the question, as my initial problem already had a solution. My concern now is the follow up.

Comment: Remove the `center` option from the `beamercolorbox` that contains the author. In orde to add a small horizontal space between author name and edge of the slide, you can use `\hspace`: `\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.2\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\hspace*{2em}\insertshortauthor\expandafter\beamer@ifempty\expandafter{\beamer@shortinstitute}{}{~~(\insertshortinstitute)}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%`

Comment: Thank you so much!